# Curve/wrap text around a circular object with magick?

Tags: r, imagemagick

I would like to add a text annotation but would like it to wrap around a circle?
For example, I can add text to anywhere in the circle. Here is an example below; I drew a blue arrow line indicating where I want the text to wrap. Is this possible? thanks in advance.

```
library(magick)
img <- image_read ('https://www.dropbox.com/s/g91f66zd34rhky3/template_1.png?dl=1' )
image_annotate(img, "1345678910110000000000000000000000", font = 'Times', size = 30, location = "+50+150" )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Drawn with ggplot2 and friends. Needs some manual tweaking of text size, text spacing, or plot size to control how much of the circle it covers.

```
library(ggplot2); library(ggforce); library(geomtextpath)

t = seq(0, 1, length.out = 100) * pi
semi_top <- data.frame(x = cos(t),
                       y = sin(t),
                       label = "1345678910110000000000000000000000")

ggplot() +
  geom_circle(aes(x0=0,y0=0,r=1), fill = "gray70") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5, 1.5)) +
  geom_textpath(data = semi_top, aes(x,y,label = label), size = 12, vjust = 1.1) +
  coord_fixed(clip = "off") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: wow I didn't even think of using ggplot2; do you know if it is possible to  create some sort of gradient, like how it looks like in power point?

Comment: I'm sure it is, but I don't know the simplest way. One could be to export with the `rvg` package and put the gradient in in office, but maybe that's too convoluted. https://github.com/davidgohel/rvg

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in Imagemagick as follows, thought not perfectly.

I create a circle image and exend it with white. Then I create text image with transparent background and -distort arc it to 180 deg. I then composite it over the circle image.  Unix syntax for IM 6 follows:

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:white -fill gray \
-draw "circle 250,250 250,0" -alpha off \
-gravity center -background white -extent 750x750 \
\( -background none -fill black -size x100 \
label:"0123456789000000000000" -distort arc "180 0 300 250" \) \
-gravity south -geometry +0+375 -compose over -composite \
x.png
```

[image]